# Sitecore images served as ashx when Media.RequestExtension setting is blank

Tags: configuration, media-library

We've just deployed to a new environment and expected images from the Media library to be referenced with their original file extensions e.g. .jpg as the `Media.RequestExtension` setting is "". They are however served as .ashx files rather than .jpg etc which is different than other environments.

I can't see any relevant differences in `App_config` and `web.config` between environments.

I know this post may be lacking details but not sure what else to include as my understanding is that the `Media.RequestExtension` setting should control this.

Comment: Just to make sure, it's Media.RequestExtension and not Media.RequestionExtension. Also can you view /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx and make sure it's actually ""  in what Sitecore is building at its config.

Comment: Sorry - that was a typo with Media.RequestionExtension. I can only view the config using showconfig on the Authoring server unfortunately

Comment: I am also having this problem and so far have not found any solutions. Did you end up solving it?

Comment: are you refering to **Media.RequestExtension** ? if its blank sitecore will return default file original extension.